# CSS Flex Box Gallery Issue

Tags: css, image, flexbox, gallery

Currently I try to create an "image gallery" with flex box.
This is what I currently have: https://jsfiddle.net/neu28Lnc/2/

The width of the images are always 50% - meaning I will always have 2 images next to each other.
Height of the page is not fixed - you should be able to scroll / add more images.

The problem I have, is that I want to remove the gaps between those images.
Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/neu28Lnc/1/  (hard coded with margins).

Usually I would use `flex-direction: column;` but since I have a no height, it will never wrap to a 2nd column.

Maybe some of you can help me with my issue / have a better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Syllz

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you also put your relevant code in the question instead of only a JSFiddle? That way it becomes easier for people to see the problem.

Comment: You need to update layout in two colums of width 50% each or use masonary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something with **css Grid**, but after all, css grid is more for grids, of course.

A grid is made of lines which supports each other. Each rectangular form drawn by those lines inevitably share a common horizontal and vertical line.

**Flexbox** is another option, but you have to set a height to your container so that columns wrap with the `flex-direction: column`.

If you have a lot of elements, and they exceed the space given by the height we have established, the container will break, with the remaining elements showing up on one side.

The best option here is **Multi-column**. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kx5Ljo5y/)

Cons:
- We can't have an item span more than 1 column.
- The items aren`t listed horizontally.

For me is the best "css only" solution.

[W3C - CSS Multiple Columns](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

Comment: Multi-column solved it for me. Was really easy to use. Thank you so much =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use masonary using grid layout. Hope this is helpful to you.

```css
.container {
     display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 20px;
}

.image {
  height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.image2 {
  height: 150px;
  background: #abc;
}

.image3 {
  height: 180px;
  background: #def;
}

.image4 {
  height: 30px;
  background: #fad;
}

.image5 {
  height: 150px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image img">img1</div>
  <div class="image2 img">img2</div>
  <div class="image3 img">img3</div>
  <div class="image4 img">img4</div>
  <div class="image5 img">img5</div>
  <div class="image img">img1</div>
  <div class="image2 img">img2</div>
  <div class="image3 img">img3</div>
  <div class="image4 img">img4</div>
  <div class="image5 img">img5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks :) your code really helped me, but has some issues with overlapping images.

Comment: You need to set `max-width: 100%` for images. Setting `max-width` would make images resize according to the size of div.